# How to add an attribute to an Enum class after declaration

Tags: python

So I have a class called Roles so I can give employees in my program roles. The below code is basically what I have so far. What I want to know though is if I wanted to add more roles in the future is there a way I can do it so that I don't have to go back and edit the Role class directly.

```
class Roles(Enum):
    WORKER = auto()
    MANAGER = auto()
```

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: The idea behind an enum is that you have a complete list of all values of that type. If you extend it and add more values, you break the most fundamental property of enums.